# Expectation of matrices

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics

I've been trying to show that $Cov(Ay,b)=Cov((I - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty), (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty) = 0$ matrix. A little context is that we assume the linear model $y = X\beta +\epsilon$, where X is design matrix and $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2 I_{n \times n}).$ b is the least square estimator equal to $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$. Show the covariance is the above.

I tried simplifying the above expression 
$Cov((I - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty), (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty) = E ((Ay - E(Ay))(b - E(b))^T)=.... =E(yy^TX(X^TX)^{-1} - y \beta^TX(X^TX)^{-1} - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Tyy^TX(X^TX)^{-1} + X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty\beta^TX(X^TX)^{-1})$

using facts like $E(y) = E(X\beta +\epsilon) = X\beta$ .

Now i'm wondering if I'm allowed to take in the matrix operator inside $E(yy^T)X(X^TX)^{-1} - E(y) \beta^TX(X^TX)^{-1} - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TE(yy^T)X(X^TX)^{-1} + X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TE(y)\beta^TX(X^TX)^{-1}$

This is because X is deterministic. 
If yes, Is iit possible to share a link to explain this and how do i further simplify this to zero. Im not very good with expectations of matrices so i cannot tell if we allowed to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can take the expectation inside. Regression models like this are conditional distributions given $X$ so $X$ is effectively a constant.

In order to simplify it, you need to know what the random stuff that you're taking the average of is. In this case, it's the residuals $\epsilon$ which you've specified are independent normals with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$.

The easy one is $E(y)$ since $$ E(y) = E(X\beta + \epsilon) = E(X\beta) + E(\epsilon) = X\beta$$ (we just used that $E(\epsilon)= 0).$

$E(yy^T)$ is a bit more involved: $$ E(yy^T) = E((X\beta + \epsilon)(\beta^T X^T+\epsilon^T)) = X\beta\beta^TX^T + E(\epsilon\epsilon^T) = X\beta\beta^TX^T  + \sigma^2I$$ where we used $E(\epsilon) = 0$ to get ride of the cross terms and the fact that $E(\epsilon\epsilon^T)$ is the covariance $\sigma^2I.$

So plug those in and simplify.

**EDIT**

Looking more closely at your computation, you have made some errors upstream. Perhaps this is just a typo but notice that $Ay = (I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)y$... the $I$ hits the $y$ too.

We have $E(b) = \beta$  and $E(Ay) = (I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)X\beta = X\beta-X\beta = 0.$

So $$ E((Ay-E(Ay))(b^T-E(b^T))) = E((Ay)(b^T-\beta^T)) \\=AE(yy^T)X(X^TX)^{-1}-AE(y)\beta^T.$$

A perhaps too generous hint: notice that $AX=0.$